# Should we use butterknife or findViewById() with Kotlin Android project as we can directly access views by id

Tags: android, kotlin, butterknife

I'm able to access my layout views(like button, TextView, EditText etc) directly inside the activity by their ids defined in layout xml file in Kotlin android project.

So, do we need to use findviewbyId(), or butterknife lib in kotlin android project?

StudentActivity.kt

````
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val studentViewModel = getStudentViewModel()

        updateButton.setOnClickListener {
            val name = nameEditText.text.toString()
            val age = ageEditText.text.toString()
            val subject = subjectEditText.text.toString()

                studentViewModel.updateStudentRecord(
                    Student(
                        name,
                        Integer.parseInt(age),
                        subject
                    )
                )

    }
}
}```
````

Comment: You can use synthetic imports just fine. I'm also using it in favor of ButterKnife. That said, see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58155708/3999808

Comment: use DataBinding Its best and also databinding is also used for many other things

Answer (score 1):

`ButterKnife` is an old solution for view binding. It has less boilerplate code than old `findviewbyId` way but because of `annotation processors` it impacts build time speed and doesn't provide `Null safety` and `Type safety`. A better solution is `kotlinx.android.synthetic` that you used in your example but it has some problems too. For example, if you set your content view to a layout, then type an id that only exists in a different layout, the IDE lets you autocomplete and add the new import statement. Unless the developer specifically checks to make sure their import statements only import the correct views, there is no safe way to verify that this won’t cause a runtime issue. As everything is global, one has to be careful to make sure that they only use views they are expecting and ignore the autocomplete. `DataBinding` and `ViewBinding`  are the best solutions for now. They are similar at first look. Both generate binding classes that you can use to reference views directly with support `Null safety` and `Type safety`, but there are differences:

- `DataBinding` approach needs you to add `<layout>` tag to your XML layout in order to enable the data binding process
- `ViewBinding` doesn’t support layout variables or layout expressions, so it can’t be used to bind layouts with data in XML

`ViewBinding` is faster than `DataBinding` in build time because it does n't use annotation processors.

Comment: Yes, You are right but Data binding is a bit complicated in the case of CustomView.

Comment: What do you mean of CustomView? @Rock

Answer (score 0):

I think you will not use anymore, just if you want? But I believe that is not because of the Synthetic Accessors, it's because of the Data Bindings and the announced this year, [View Binding](https://proandroiddev.com/new-in-android-viewbindings-the-difference-from-databinding-library-bef5945baf5e)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, here is the the magic of kotlin. Just use your id from the layout file (xml) and directly use it. Like:
            `button.setOnClickListener {}`
and so on. hope it will help.