# Kotlin Android View Binding: Kotlin Android Extension Problem

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to do View Binding in Kotlin and fragments.

```
val button: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.Rutton)
button.setOnClickListener{
    //do something here.
}
```

but when it has many objects. I need to define that.
So I had to look at:

[Kotlin Android View Binding: findViewById vs Butterknife vs Kotlin Android Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482018/kotlin-android-view-binding-findviewbyid-vs-butterknife-vs-kotlin-android-exten)

and

[Android developers documentation DataStore Overview: View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#kotlin)

but I can't find `ResultProfileBinding` in my Android Studio

What can I do in my program?

Comment: What is your *layout file* name you have keep ? Also check if you have added *dataBinding* enabled in *build.gradle* file or not.

Comment: It's ```fragment_fast_login_page.xml```, and I put ```buildFeatures { viewBinding true }``` in my build.gradle

Comment: Then try to right *FragmentFastLoginBinding* like

*private lateinit var binding: FragmentFastLoginBinding* it's basically depends on your layout file name.

Comment: Error message: ```Unresolved reference: FragmentFastLoginBinding```

Comment: Did you have done required *import* pls check once..

Comment: I checked the suggestions, but I didn't find one about a similar layout file name.

Comment: *R. id. **R**utton*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you followed every instruction of the link you just posted, Specially the setup instructions, you should be able to import `ResultProfileBinding`.

Keep in mind that this `********Binding` class will have the same name of the layout file. Per example, if your layout file is `my_own_layout.xml` the binding class will be `MyOwnLayoutBinding`. In this particular case they called their layout file `result_profile.xml`

Comment: @jortas_mr.json My Android Version is 4.1.1. I had already added ```buildFeatures { viewBinding true }```in my build grade(app), but I think it was not changed at my project settings.